# Displaying just the last element of a class in each scope

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following HTML layout:

```
ul
  li
    div.foo
    div.foo
    div.foo
    div.bar  
  li
    div.foo
    div.foo
    div.foo
    div.foo
    div.foo
  li
    div.foo
    div.foo
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.foo {display: none;}
```

I would like to have the last element in each `li` to be `display: block;`.

Currently, I have :

```
$('li .foo:last').show();
```

But this just displays the very last `div.foo` instead of the last `div.foo` in each `li` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.foo:last` as context for each `li` should do it :

```
$('.foo:last', 'li').show();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PJguN/)

The above is just a shortcut for `$('li').find('.foo:last')`, or even more verbose `$('li').find('.foo').filter(':last')`

Comment: That did it.  Forgot about the power of contexts.  Thanks for the wakeup call.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to do it like this:

```
$('li .foo:last-child').show();
```

`:last` is a special jQuery selector that just gets the last one in the collection.

Comment: Problem with this is, if the `div.foo` isn't the last element in the `li`, it doesn't get shown.

Comment: This is also what my answer was going to be.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative & an extended version in addition to adeneo's answer using `each()`

```
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).find('div.foo:last').show();
});
```